# apache poi - missing cells data

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have 14 rows X 96 columns of data in my excel. The problem that I am having right now is that when I output the result, only the first row contain full data of all columns, but the next row, it only contain around half of 96 total columns. I couldn't figure it out why it happens. please help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:xx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row = null;
        XSSFCell cell = null;
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();


        for (Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.rowIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {

                cell = row.getCell(i);
                String stringcell = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                al.add(stringcell);`
             }


          System.out.println(al);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getPhysicalNumberOfCells--): "Gets the number of defined cells (NOT number of cells in the actual row!). That is to say if only columns 0,4,5 have values then there would be 3." Try using `for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++)` or the `cellIterator` of the `Row` instead.

Comment: @AxelRichter it solved my problem. thank you for your time Sir !

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:xx"));
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row = null;
    XSSFCell cell = null;
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();


    for (Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.rowIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {

            cell = row.getCell(i);
            String stringcell = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            al.add(stringcell);`
         }


      System.out.println(al);

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

as suggested by Axel Richer, now all data are visible 
from

```
  for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++)
```